# На андроиде в хроме не выбирается значение select'a

Tags: android, html, jquery, google-chrome

На андроиде в хроме не выбирается значение select'a. При изменении остается то значение, которое было по-умолчанию. Самая обычная форма. Можно ли как-то решить это с помощью jQuery или другим способом?

```
<select id="FormField_11">
  <option value="">Choose a Country</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
</select>
```